# How to use NSGA-II (in python/pymoo library) to select optimal value pairs from a list

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

**Context:** I need to implement NSGA-II in python for the following 2-objective optimisation problem: I have a set of items each having two non-bounded values: one for cost, and the other for quality of service. For instance:

`[(item1, cost=0.4, QoS=0.89),(item2, cost=0.67, QoS=0.42),(item3, cost=0.02, QoS=0.53)]`

**Objective:** The aim is to apply a multi-objective optimisation algorithm (e.g., NSGA-II) in order to choose the most optimal item(s), i.e., the one(s) with optimal (minimal) cost and optimal (maximal) QoS. Moreover, we aim to compare various optimisation algorithms (we are just starting with NSGA-II).

**Problem:** I already checked the pymoo library: https://pypi.org/project/pymoo/0.1.2/ and my main issue is defining the optimisation "problem" prior to executing the NSGA-II algorithm. Because my input is not the objective functions but pairs of values (cost, QoS). So how can I input this array of pairs into the NSGA-II algorithm in order to find the optimal pair(s) ?

I am completely new to optimisation algorithms, so perhaps my methodology is wrong and I'm sure that I must be missing something(s). Any help/explanation would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Elio Mansour, were you able to find a workaround? I am trying to solve a similar problem.. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend formulating your problem mathematically or in a structured way. Our [getting started guide](https://pymoo.org/getting_started.html) explains how to implement a problem given a mathematical expression. Having implemented your problem is becomes fairly easy to use [pymoo](https://pymoo.org/) to benchmark different algorithms. 
Also, I would like to mention that the newest release of pymoo is version 0.4.1 which has been released recently. 
Without any more details about your problem that is what I recommend you to have a look at.